# window.rootViewController returns nil when I try to access the root controller from App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In iOS 13 I have set up my app that works fine and the window's root controller is a tab bar controller and I have done this setup in my scene delegate.

I am trying to implement a logic where when a user clicks on a notification, it has to launch the app and navigate to a particular tab. Say tab number 3. I do this in the didReceive response function in the app delegate. Everything works except for the fact that when I try to access the tab view controller, it seems to return a nil and the code beyond that line is never executed (obv because the root view controller of UIApplication seems to return nil)

Here is the code for my scene delegate class:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        let mainTabController = MainTabController()
        mainTabController.selectedIndex = 1
        
        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else {return}
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        self.window = window
        self.window?.rootViewController = mainTabController
    }
}
```

Here is the code for what I do when user clicks on a notification (app delegate)

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        if let partnerUid = userInfo["receivedFromId"] as? String{
            pushWhenUserClicksOnChat(partnerUid: partnerUid)
        }
    }
    
    func pushWhenUserClicksOnChat(partnerUid: String){
        if let mainTabController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController as? MainTabController{
              //navigate to desired location
              //but this block is not executed. Main tab controller is nil.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From IOS 13 you need to get `window` from `sceneDelegate` like this

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
    guard var rootViewController = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController else {
        return
    }

    // change your view controller here
    rootViewController = UIViewController()
}
```

Comment: in iOS 13 and above, if i get the window using `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow', it should be nil ?